# Nodered - inject javascript at runtime

Tags: javascript, templates, node-red

I am trying to run a script at runtime, like this simple example:

[image]

I have tried a angular method and simple script method.  I cant get either to work.  Should this be possible?

```
[{"id":"4e95c60f043d8467","type":"inject","z":"6c6ab8919eac0a16","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":770,"y":660,"wires":[["a88ea140550ac060","86f6ec38365c39ac"]]},{"id":"a88ea140550ac060","type":"ui_template","z":"6c6ab8919eac0a16","group":"49ecf28f914827db","name":"Hide","order":4,"width":0,"height":0,"format":"\n<script>\n    (function(scope) {\n\n        scope.$watch('msg.payload', function(data) {\n                    console.log('hiding');\n            document.getElementById(\"Everything_Tomorrow_cards\")style.display = \"none\";\n        });\n    })(scope);\n</script>","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"resendOnRefresh":true,"templateScope":"local","className":"","x":950,"y":660,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"86f6ec38365c39ac","type":"ui_template","z":"6c6ab8919eac0a16","group":"49ecf28f914827db","name":"Alert","order":4,"width":0,"height":0,"format":"\n<script>\n    alert(\"mytest\");\n</script>","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"resendOnRefresh":true,"templateScope":"local","className":"","x":950,"y":700,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"49ecf28f914827db","type":"ui_group","name":"Tomorrow","tab":"2251edb4fa777071","order":4,"disp":true,"width":"14","collapse":false,"className":""},{"id":"2251edb4fa777071","type":"ui_tab","name":"Everything","icon":"dashboard","order":1,"disabled":false,"hidden":true}]
```

Example of a HIDE:

```
<script>
    (function(scope) {

        scope.$watch('msg.payload', function(data) {
                    console.log('hiding');
            document.getElementById("Everything_Tomorrow_cards")style.display = "none";
        });
    })(scope);
</script>
```

Comment: This is not very clear... According to the title of your question, I would want to say to you to see this function: [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but I'm not sure it will answer your problem.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70354902/edit) the question to include what's in the template nodes (as text not screen shots) so we don't need to import the flow to see what you are trying to do.